# Firebase Realtime Database - How to subscribe to database additions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a collection of notes in my Firebase realtime database. 
My clients subscribe to modifications in the ***/notes*** path of the database. 
But when "client A" adds a new note the data is not pushed to "client B".

```
export const startSubscribeNotes = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const uid = getState().auth.uid

    database.ref('notes')
    .orderByChild(`access/members/${uid}`)
    .equalTo(true)
    .on('value', (snapshot) => {
      console.log('notes .on()')
      let updatednotes = []
      snapshot.forEach( (data) => {
        const note = {
          id: data.key,
          ...data.val()
        }
        updatednotes.push(note)
      })
      dispatch(setnotes(notes))
    })
  }
}
```

My database structure
[image: Database structure]

My Firebase access rules

```
"notes": {
  ".indexOn": ["data/title", "access/author"],      
  //entry-level access
  ".read": "
    auth.uid !== null && query.equalTo === auth.uid
  ",
  "$note_id": {
    ".write": "
      //If new data
      (!data.exists() && auth.uid !== null) ||
      (
        data.child('access').child('author').val() === auth.uid 
      ||
        data.child('access/members').child(auth.uid).exists()
      )
    ",
    "data": {
      //access
      ".read": "
        //if author or assigned user
        data.parent().child('access').child('author').val() === auth.uid ||
        data.parent().child('access/members').child(auth.uid).exists()
      "
    }
  }
}
```

The access rules above are meant to prevent clients from reading all "notes".

However - A new note created by "client A" that "client B" **has access to** never gets pushed to "client B". If "client B" reloads the application the new note appears - but that defeats the purpose of subscriptions.

How can I make sure that additions to the **/notes** node gets pushed to my clients with access rules in place?

Answer (score 0):

The above code works. The problem was in `dispatch(setnotes(notes))`.
I accidentally did some extra checks that did not pass all notes to the array. :/ Therefore I dispatched the wrong data to the store. Dispatching the correct `updatednotes` solved the problem. /K